# Is mast*rbating as a teenager haram to do?

Tags: masturbation

I'm sorry, i know this is an embarrassing question to ask, but since this is anonymous anyways and i need to know it. Is it haram when you mast*rbate as a teenager?! Because of the hormones we can't control it sometimes so it just happens. Is it a sin because most of the time I do regret it but it just happens.

Comment: Another question about masturbation. We really don't need more. Please check the site before asking. I guess just by clicking on the first five posts that a click on your chosen tag will display you will find an answer of your question.

Comment: i' m sorry i didn' t know

Comment: Since we have so many of these types of questions, I will give an answer in 10 words, "Sin. Fast and lower gaze. Break habit. Allah is forgiving."

Answer (score 0):

Okay so, It is understanding about the hormones and all but, you know it really is the waswasa that is making you do it! anytime you have that feeling, go and read some Quran, or even Al Nas, Al Falaq, and Al Iklas!
those will chase all the bad Jinns, Shaytan, and the Waswasa!
Lailah.